# when i m open another accordin in reich text area field wants difrrent vale

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<lightning-accordion onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection}>
            <template if:true={processing}>
              <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..."  size="small">
                             </lightning-spinner>
              </template>
         <template for:each={data} for:item="bd" for:index="pq">
                   <div key={bd.id}  >
               <lightning-accordion-section name={bd.Id}label{bd.RFP_Question_Text__c} >
                               <lightning-combobox
                                       label='Compliance Response'
                                       options={options}
                                        onchange={handleChange}
                                  ></lightning-combobox>             
                      <br>  
 <lightning-input-rich-text label="Response Text" required value={getfromKnoeldge} label-visible="true" onchange={reponsetext} ></lightning-input-rich-text>
                   
                      <br>
                      <br>
           <lightning-button  label="Save response" variant="brand" onclick={saverep} ></lightning-button>
                </lightning-accordion-section> 
            </div> 
          </template>
      </lightning-accordion>
```

[image]

so basically I want when I'm open second accordion I m able to pass another value in second rich text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you iterating over the **data** variable, you need to add a property on the data array.

for ex -

```
data = [
  {
    Id: "1",
    value: "some value",
  },
 {
    Id: "2",
    value: "other value",
  },
];
```

```
 <template for:each="{data}" for:item="bd" for:index="pq">
  <div key="{bd.id}">
    <lightning-accordion-section name="{bd.Id}label{bd.RFP_Question_Text__c}">
      <lightning-combobox
        label="Compliance Response"
        options="{options}"
        onchange="{handleChange}"
      ></lightning-combobox>
      <br />
      <lightning-input-rich-text
        label="Response Text"
        required
        value={bd.value} // dynamic value
        label-visible="true"
        onchange="{reponsetext}"
      ></lightning-input-rich-text>

      <br />
      <br />
      <lightning-button
        label="Save response"
        variant="brand"
        onclick="{saverep}"
      ></lightning-button>
    </lightning-accordion-section>
  </div>
</template>
```